# Корректно ли обращение: "Их родители"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, обращение

«Мальчишки и девчонки, а также их родители, весёлые истории увидеть не хотите ли?» Это слова из песенки, которой  начинался киножурнал «Ералаш». Я всегда считал, что подобное обращение (их родители) — не более чем шутка в духе юмористического журнала, однако недавно услышал по радио серьезное объявление примерно такого содержания: "Пострадавшие и члены их семей, просим вас обратиться...".
Я думаю, что каждое обращение должно быть так сказать независимым, то есть не содержать притяжательных местоимений. Если это коснется меня, то я бы не хотел, чтобы ко мне обратились в форме "его родитель" и "член его семьи". Прав ли я?

Answer (score 2):

Очень интересный вопрос. Диссонанс здесь весьма заметен, но с чем он связан? Вероятно, здесь не только с невежливостью проблема, но и с грамматикой. Прямое обращение обычно *нейтрально* про отношению к грамматическому лицу (далее может следовать любой текст), хотя иногда может содержать личное местоимение 2-го лица (/вы, /мальчишки и девчонки). В нашем случае этот нейтралитет *разрушается* привязкой к первой части обращения притяжательного местоимения 3-го лица: эта часть *перестаёт быть обращением* - мальчишки и девчонки воспринимаются как "**они**". По-видимому, грамматическая несочетаемость двух частей обращения и создаёт диссонанс. Само же по себе притяжательное местоимение 2-го (*ваше величество*) и даже 3-го лица, если оно не ссылается на другое обращение, грамматически может входить в состав обращения (Отечество в опасности. Доблестные *сыны и дочери его*, ... !). Всё исправляется, если исходное обращение перевести в косвенную форму: "*Мы обращаемся к мальчишкам и девчонкам, а также к их родителям*". Во втором примере при сохранении прямой формы обращения нужно исключить местоимение: "*и члены семей пострадавших*".

Answer (score 1):

Да, а вопрос-то любопытный. 
Я со своей колокольни, мне не версия  Alex_ander'а непонятна, потому, быть может, что в ней нет четкой формулировки, считать ли ошибкой - и если да, то как классифицировать.
Так вот, я думаю, что ошибки как таковой нет, но по возможности такого использования следует избегать - по причинам, о которых я сейчас скажу.

Перво-наперво, никакой невежливости или вообще нарушения этикетных норм тут нет. Для и сам подход такой был бы надуман. Невежливость при обращение - это несоответствие "физическому" контексту, статусу, например, лица к которому обращаются. Иных типов невежливости при обращения просто не знаю.

Далее. Что у нас с грамматикой. Я и тут не вижу каких-либо нарушений. Никакая грамматика (в обычном понимании) не препятствует использованию притяжательного местоимения там, где безусловно возможно притяжательное прилагательное.

И наконец стиль. Шероховатость чувствуется. Достаточно четко и определенно. 
То есть копать надо где-то на границе грамматики и стиля. Видимо, какое-то семантическое или околосемантическое препятствие. Больше просто нечему.

Все до данного момента сказанное можно считать имеющим авторитетное обоснование, да вряд ли кто и возразит тут что-то. Дальше уже мои личные фантазии, прошу к ним так и относиться.

Как верно было замечено, небольшие изменения конструкции сразу снимают все проблемы. То есть дело именно в том, что первая часть обращения, само её существование, как-то мешает использованию притяжательного местоимения. В том и только том случае, когда притяжательное местоимение должно бы ссылаться на само обращение, его предшествующую часть.

Вообще-то тем самым уже напрашивается привлечение аппарата контекстных грамматик, но это, видимо слишком мощное средство, попробую рассуждать на более доступном уровне. Попробуем обратиться к самому понятию "обращения". Что это такое? Ведь это просто утерянный в русском звательный падеж. Знающий украинский (или любой другой язык с активной формой звательного) уже, наверное, догадается куда я клоню.

Звательную форму невозможно "нагрузить" притяжательным местоимением. Научно доказать что это так, я не берусь, но пояснить попытаюсь. Во-первых, почему это так, вернее чем это может быть предопределено. Ну в качестве какого-то объяснения я бы посмотрел на сам звательный падеж. Это ж ведь не просто "неназывной" вариант именительного, он похитрее будет. В нем теряются часть свойств имени, зато появляются некоторые признаки предикатива.

Я далек от мысли объявить звательный падеж сказуемым (тем более глаголом), но согласитесь, в нем есть определенные признаки действия. Ну хотя бы потому, что он теряет качество субъектности-объектности. Он и не субъект, и не объект. Черт его знает, что он такое, высказывание какое-то, предикатив. А коли так то на него и не может быть распространена семантика притяжательности. Уффф...

Последнее пояснение. Чувство исторического звательного совершенно утеряно носителями современного русского, грамматика его не восстанвливается на бытовом уровне.
Но ведь есть и новая звательная форма (Петь! Маш! Теть!). Вот с ней и поиграемся. *"Мальчик Петя и его родители! Подойдите к Деду Морозу за подарками."* Ну как говорится, на грани. Ну ведь это и не звательный в чистом виде... *Петя и его родители!* Уже хочется поправить. Причем среди прочих вариантов даже *Петя и **твои** родители* где-то мелькает. То есть затруднения есть, но не все так плохо. Но попробуйте ***"Петь и его родители!"*** - вот он, разрыв шаблона и вынос мозга. Нету у "Петь" притяжательного местоимения. Семантически быть не может.  Согласны?!

Но почему же все-аки я настаиваю, что ошибки нет?! Да потому именно, что русский язык давно забыл грамматику звательного, а единичные формы "новозвательного" погоды не делают. Грамматический звательный воспринимается просто как вариант именительного. Отсюда и потенциальная возможность вопреки остаточному чувству грамматики звательного таки сопоставить ему притяжательное местоимение.

Иное дело в украинском. *"Петр та його батьки"* (Им.) - все абсолютно нормально. *"Петро та його батьки! Ласкава запрошуемо вас..."* (зв.) - режет слух как нож по чугуну. Поспрашиваю еще украинцев, но почти уверен, что тут не ошибся.

Прошу еще раз извинить за некоторый сумбур в изложении, писал совершенно с чистого листа. Экспромтом. Раньше в этот вопрос совершенно не влезал. Отсюда и непричесанность мысли.

(+)
Меня поправили с примером на украинском. Я согласился, использование русской формы имени не лучшая идея для убедительности аргументации. Ну заменим на что-то более родное украинскому.
"Петрусю, синку та його батьки!* - та же корявость, ещё даже очевиднее.

Comment: Замечание к примеру в конце ответа. Предложение с "Петр" в украинском режет слух намного сильнее. Потому что там вообще нет такого имени (язык не повернётся так сказать). Украинское имя в именительном падеже как раз **Петро** (в звательном — Петре). Так что в этом примере слух Вам режет что-то совсем другое, может, просто непривычность неродного языка.

Comment: @grizzly - Да согласен, спасибо. Перемудрил я с этим примером... Суржик получился, а апелляция к нему - это не лучший выбор для аргументации... Но вот насчет "непривычности" - это уже надуманное объяснение. У вас же есть более правдоподобная версия - использование именительного там, где звательный требуется.  Но я поиграюсь с более. Нехай він Петрусь буде. Вот уж точно.форма чисто украинская.

Comment: Я не возражаю против самого ответа. У меня нет аргументов ни за, ни против, даже чувство языка молчит.

Comment: @grizzly да я вас понял прекрасно... Я тоже сейчас говорил только про пример на украинском.. В ответ добавил.

Comment: В исправленном примере основная корявость в том, что кто-то из родителей обращается к самому себе. Я носитель языка и для меня обращение "Увага! Петрусю та його батьки! Будьте обережнi..." звучит не хуже, чем "мальчишки и девчонки, а также их родители".

Comment: @grizzly *кто-то из родителей обращается к самому себе* - ??? Я пример специально конструировал немного комичный, но такого смысла не вкладывал вовсе. Ну замените "сінку" на "хлопче". *звучит не хуже* - Єто понял, спасибо. Сравню с тем, что мне другие эксперты скажут.

Comment: Нет ли в подобном обращении закавыки, связанной с тем, что тот, к кому обращаются через местоимение, "должен" бы предшествующее _обращение к другим_ пропустить мимо ушей, "забыть"?

Comment: @Alex_ander  я думал об этом. Вы о том, что обращение (первое в ряду) требует  по смыслу второго лица, а в дальнейшем происходит не мотивированный контекстом переход на третье? Ну, собственно, это и есть то самое предполагаемое свойство звательного падежа, которое я поставил во главу своего объяснения...